# Prebuild 3rd party dependencies and distribute them in a binary format

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, xcframework

My project has around 20 3rd party dependencies, and I'm considering pre-building and distributing them as a binary framework to speed up the build time.

To do this, I am creating a new Framework project in Xcode and adding dependencies with Swift Package Manager (I'm doing it the same way in the original project).

By following [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle), I am enabling `BUILD_BINARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` and disabling `SKIP_INSTALL` flag for my target.

So my Framework A depends on third parties B and C and I want to use `import B` or `import C` in my host application, that consumes the Framework A.

There are a few problems that I am facing with:

1. When I am doing an `import B` in the Framework A code, I see a warning:

```
Module 'B' was not compiled with library evolution support; using it means binary compatibility for 'A' can't be guaranteed.
```

That could be fixed by making an `@_implementationOnly import B`, but after doing it, I'll not be able to import B from the host application.

2. Even if I will create an xcframework, add it to my host application, I see a `.swiftinterface` file that tells:

```
No such module B
```

That is a side-effect of issue one, I suppose.

**Update:**
I tried to build it from scratch:
I have a `Framework A` that depends on `Framework B`, which is a static framework that I'm archiving with `SKIP_INSTALL=false` and `BUILD_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=true`. After dragging and drop it to framework A, I can import it into any of the files in `Framework A`, I simply invoke a function from B in the A constructor and archiving A for distribution.

I have an error with undefined symbols when I creating an instance of framework A in my host application:

```
Undefined symbol: _$s10FrameworkB0A6AClassCBCycfc
Undefined symbol: _$s10FrameworkB0A6BClassCMa
```

Interesting, that I have the same error even if I'm doing an import of B with `@_implementationOnly`.

So my question is, does someone tried doing something like this before? Am I completely missing something?